# Not able to see the log file in Yii

Tags: php, model-view-controller, logging, yii

I am not able to see the log files in Yii framwork. By default it saves in "protected/runtime". Here is my config in main:

```
'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLoCFileLogRoutegRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning, info',
                    'categories'=>'system.*',
                ))),
```

and this is how I'm logging:

```
Yii::log("Index Checkout", "profile", 'system.web.CController');
Yii::trace('IndexCheckout', 'system.web.CController');
```

Not getting any error but can't find any log file.

Any idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be something wrong name with your log class `CLoCFileLogRoutegRouter`. It should be `CLogRouter`

```
'log' => array(
    'class' => 'CLogRouter',
        'routes' => array(
            array(
                'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels' => 'error, warning, info',
                    'categories'=>'system.*',
                ),
```

Comment: That looks like he typed a new class name in the middle of an old one, accidentally without removing it first. :) I wonder though why no error was reported...

Answer (score 8):

Even though the question is already answered

Please consider that Yii writes logs after the main script is ended, So if you terminate your script using **die()** command, you never let Yii write it down. To avoid such problems you should terminate the script using **Yii::app()->end()** command.

[For more information see here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#message-routing)

Comment: Explain your definition of properly, There is Cause (die()), Solution (Yii::app()->end()) and also a proof (reference to the framework page). The question is not a about a Concept, it's just a simple bug and I don't think further information is needed.

Comment: thanks! `exit;` has the same side effect as `die();` do

Answer (score 2):

You are configuring your log to only log messages related to 'error, warning, and info',

And you are trying to Log, "trace" (Yii::trace) and "profile" levels, thats why you are not getting anything.

Also: dont try to log "profile" things on you own, there are specific methods for that, namely [Yii::beginProfile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#beginProfile-detail) and [Yii::endProfile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#endProfile-detail), read more about profiling at [the yii guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#performance-profiling)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a permissions problem. Is the runtime directory writable by your web server (Apache)?

Comment: To add further info, Im on WAMP and yes the directory has the permission already.